# Vue.component on Vue 2 + Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade, vite

I have this code in app.js in ressources/assets/js/ on Laravel :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueInternationalization from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueInternationalization);
const lang = document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2);
const i18n = new VueInternationalization({
    locale: lang,
    messages: Locale
});

Vue.component('field', require('./components/Field.vue').default);
Vue.component('fileField', require('./components/FileField.vue').default);
....

window.vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    i18n,
});
```

All works fine on Laravel 8 with Vue but i switch to Laravel 10 with Vue 2 + Vite, and i have this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on g.component("field", require("./components/Field.vue").default);
```

If someone could help me... thanks !

I try to change :

```
Vue.component('field', require('./components/Field.vue').default);
```

with :

```
import Field from './components/Field.vue';
Vue.component('field', Field);
import FileField from './components/FileField.vue';
Vue.component('fileField', FileField);
```

but i have a blank page with this in body :

```
<!--function(a,s,o,u){return Ci(e,a,s,o,u,!0)}-->
```